# How to allow for another index string to run a script

Tags: javascript

I have no script abilitiy, but i'd like to edit an existing script which is currently restricting the script from running on any page other then the one that has a certain string in the URL.

Here is the snippet of the script which limits it from running

```
if(location.href.indexOf("MODULE=MESSAGE")>0||location.href.indexOf("/message")>0)
```

This only allows the script to run on these pages

`mysite/2014/home/11609?MODULE=MESSAGE1`

and the pages range from `Message1` to `Message20`

`mysite/2014/home/11609?MODULE=MESSAGE20`

I would like to also allow the script to be loaded and ran on these pages

`mysite/2014/options?L=11609&O=247&SEQNO=1&PRINTER=1`

where the `SEQNO=1`  ranges from `1` to `SEQNO=20`, just like the `MESSAGE1`-`MESSAGE20` do

Can someone show me how i can edit that small snippet of script to allow the `SEQNO` string found in the url to work also.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just remove the condition altogether? Otherwise, just add more `or` conditions to match `SEQNO`

Comment: i can only load on either of the 2 strings , can you illustrate and or condition to match SEQNO ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't just remove the condition altogether (there's not enough context to know if that's an option), you can just add another or condition (`||`) like so:

```
if(location.href.indexOf("MODULE=MESSAGE")>0
    ||location.href.indexOf("/message")>0
    ||location.href.indexOf("SEQNO=")>0)
```

Note that the second clause there isn't actually being used in any of your examples, so could potentially be removed. Also note that this isn't actually checking for a number so it isn't restricted to `Message1` to `Message20` as you suggest. It would match `Message21` or even `MessageFoo`. That may or may not be a problem for you. You can make the conditions as restrictive or as lose as makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check for the existence of `"SEQNO"`, simply duplicate what is being done for `"MODULE_MESSAGE"`.

```
if(location.href.indexOf("MODULE=MESSAGE")>0 ||
    location.href.indexOf("SEQNO=")>0 ||
    location.href.indexOf("/message")>0)
```

If you want to also ensure that "MESSAGE" ends in 1-20, and "SEQNO=" ends in 1-20, you can use a regex.

```
// create the end part of the regex, which checks for numbers 1-20
var regexEnd = "([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)[^0-9]*$";
// create the individual regexes
var messageRegex = new RegExp("MODULE=MESSAGE" + regexEnd);
var seqnoRegex = new RegExp("SEQNO=" + regexEnd);

// now comes your if statement, using the regex test() function, which returns true if it matches
if(messageRegex.test(location.href) ||
    seqnoRegex.test(location.href) ||
    location.href.indexOf("/message")>0)
```